# github push difficulties for new repository

Tags: github

I have attempted to add a new repository to github per their usual instructions with an odd rejection...

```
Owner@Owner-HP ~/Bescrewed
$ git push -u origin master
ERROR: Permission to TangibleDream/Bescrewed.git denied to TangibleDream/demo_app.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Owner@Owner-HP ~/Bescrewed
```

The problem is, demo_app was my last repository.  The one I'm doing presently is bescrewed and should be in no way connected to demo_app.

Has anyone had this issue before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be tied to an ssh issue as described in [GitHub help page](http://help.github.com/ssh-issues/):

> Permission to `user/repo2` denied to `user/repo1`
>
> **This error occurs when you attach your key as a [deploy key](http://help.github.com/deploy-keys/) on `repo1`**.
> You can push and pull from that repo without issue, but you won’t have access to any other repo with your key.
> To solve this, remove the key from `repo1`’s deploy keys and attach it on your [account page](https://github.com/account) instead. This key will now have access to all repos your account has access to.

See [Deploy Keys](http://help.github.com/deploy-keys/)

> What are deploy keys?
>
> Deploy keys are ssh keys just like the ones you attach to your account to allow you to push to and pull from your repos.
> The only difference is that deploy keys are designed to allow access to a single private repo.
> This will allow your staging or production server to pull in from your repo

---

The other possibility is that somehow your 'origin' remote is incorrect (check what [`git remote -v`](http://gitref.org/remotes/) returns)